# Python - Fastest way to print comparison results of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe's with 3 million records each. I need to compare both and display for every matching index, the column name where mismatch happens and the data in those mismatched columns.

Below is an example of dataframe's and expected output:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2013-11-23','2013-11-24','2013-11-25','2013-11-26','2013-11-27'],
    'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery','Apple'],
    'Num':[10.2,22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2],
    'Color':['Green','Yellow','Orange','Green','Green']
    })

df2=pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2013-11-23','2013-11-24','2013-11-25','2013-11-26','2013-11-27'],
    'Fruit':['Banana1','Orange','Apple','Celery','Apple'],
    'Num':[10.2,22.12,8.60,7.6,10.2],
    'Color':['Green','Yellow1','Orange','Green','Green']
    })

df1.set_index("Date",inplace = True)
df2.set_index("Date",inplace = True)

Dataframe 1:
             Fruit   Num   Color
Date                            
2013-11-23  Banana  10.2   Green
2013-11-24  Orange  22.1  Yellow
2013-11-25   Apple   8.6  Orange
2013-11-26  Celery   7.6   Green
2013-11-27   Apple  10.2   Green

DataFrame 2:
              Fruit    Num    Color
Date                               
2013-11-23  Banana1  10.21    Green
2013-11-24   Orange  22.12  Yellow1
2013-11-25    Apple   8.60   Orange
2013-11-26   Celery   7.60    Green
2013-11-27    Apple  10.20    Green

Expected OUTPUT:
Date 2013-11-23 has mismatch in columns ['Fruit' , 'Num'].
DF1: ['Banana',10.2]
DF2: ['Banana1', 10.21]
--------------------------------------------------------
Date 2013-11-24 has mismatch in columns ['Num' , 'Color'].
DF1: [22.1,'Yellow']
DF2: [22.12,'Yellow1']
----------------------------------------------------------
And so on for every Date index
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html

Comment: `The code that i have` - please read and include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as .py and run it

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd


def compare(data):
    df1_data, df2_data = data
    date = df1_data[0]
    d1 = df1_data[1]
    d2 = df2_data[1]

    # print(d1)
    # print(d2)
    cmp = d1 != d2
    if any(cmp):
        print('Date ', date, end=' ')

        diff_cols = cmp[cmp].index.tolist()
        d1_diff = d1[diff_cols]
        d2_diff = d2[diff_cols]

        print('has mismatch in columns', diff_cols, '.')
        print('DF1:', d1_diff.tolist())
        print('DF2:', d2_diff.tolist())
        print('-'*20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': ['2013-11-23', '2013-11-24', '2013-11-25', '2013-11-26', '2013-11-27'],
        'Fruit': ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Celery', 'Apple'],
        'Num': [10.2, 22.1, 8.6, 7.6, 10.2],
        'Color': ['Green', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Green']
    })

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': ['2013-11-23', '2013-11-24', '2013-11-25', '2013-11-26', '2013-11-27'],
        'Fruit': ['Banana1', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Celery', 'Apple'],
        'Num': [10.2, 22.12, 8.60, 7.6, 10.2],
        'Color': ['Green', 'Yellow1', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Green']
    })

    df1.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
    df2.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

    n_cpu = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(n_cpu-2)
    results = pool.map(compare, zip(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows()))
```

Output

```
Date  2013-11-23 has mismatch in columns ['Fruit'] .
DF1: ['Banana']
DF2: ['Banana1']
--------------------
Date  2013-11-24 has mismatch in columns ['Num', 'Color'] .
DF1: [22.1, 'Yellow']
DF2: [22.12, 'Yellow1']
--------------------
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Let me try this out!

Comment: Make sure you load your data in a function or under if __name__ == "__main__":. Otherwise, when it launches a new process, the data will be reloaded and you may run out of memory.

Comment: Hi, Could you tell what the first 4 lines of the compare function are doing?

Comment: The data variable is a tuple of rows from each data frame. The first line is unpack it into two rows. Each row consists of index (date) and a tuple of columns.

Comment: Since the compare function takes very short time to run. I'm not sure if it will improve performance. If not, you have to modify it slightly by sending multiple rows  to the function.

Comment: ok, so using zip the data variable sends 1 row from each dataframe(total 2 rows), in every function call.